# For loop with eval not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My first time writing my own javascript/jQuery for-loop and I'm running into trouble.

Basically, I have a series of divs which are empty, but when a button is clicked, the divs turn into input fields for the user. The input fields are there at the outset, but I'm using CSS to hide them and using JS/jQuery to evaluate the css property and make them visible/hide upon a button click.

I can do this fine by putting an id tag on each of the 7 input fields and writing out the jQuery by hand, like this:

```
$('#tryBTN').click(function(){
 if ( $('#password').css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
      $('#password').css('visibility','visible');
 else
   $('#password').css('visibility','hidden');
}
```

Copy/pasting that code 7 times and just swapping out the div IDs works great, however, being more efficient, I know there's a way to put this in a for-loop.

Writing this code as a test, it worked on the first one just fine:

```
$('#tryBTN').click(function() {
  for(i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    if($('#input1').css('visibility') == 'hidden')
      $('#input1').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }
});
```

But again, this only works for the one id. So I changed all the HTML id tags from unique ones to like id="intput1" - all the way out to seven so that I could iterate over the tags with an eval. I came up with this:

```
$('#tryBTN').click(function () {
    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        if ($(eval('input' + i)).css('visibility') == 'hidden')
            $('input' + i).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
});
```

When I put in the eval stuff - it doesn't work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. A sample of the HTML looks like this:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="page">Description: Specifies page to return if paging is selected. Defaults to no paging.</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input7" aria-describedby="page">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: why you need eval ? what if you try without

Comment: On a side note, ever notice how close `eval` is to `evil`? Anyway, please post a more complete sample of your HTML.

Comment: Use class, whatever you do...

Comment: I don't know of another way to accomplish what I'm doing without it (other than doing if statements for every separate ID and pulling it out of the for-loop).

Comment: You NEVER need to use eval to add a string.... Please forget that eval exists.

Comment: check the line below, are you using eval ? no :) and it's the same

Comment: Look at your code, look at the one that works and one that does not. Notice anything? `$('#input1')` vs `$('input' + i)`

Comment: Yes. I got it.$('#tryBTN').click(function () {
    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        if ($('#input' + i).css('visibility') == 'hidden')
            $('#input' + i).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
});

Comment: i will help you : it's the ID

Answer (score 1):

You were forgetting the `#`:

```
$('#tryBTN').click(function () {
  for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    var el = $('#input' + i); // <-- The needed `#`
    if (el.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
      el.css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Intervalia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47895692/1202830) explains the simple error in your code (the missing `#`), and the comments explain why you should never use `eval()` unless you absolutely know it's the right tool for the job - which is very rare.

I would like to add a suggestion that will simplify your code and make it more reliable.

Instead of manually setting sequential IDs on each of your `input` elements, I suggest giving them all a common class. Then you can let jQuery loop through them and you won't have to worry about updating the `7` if you ever add or remove an item.

This class can be in addition to any other classes you already have on the elements. I'll call it `showme`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control showme" aria-describedby="page">
```

Now you can use `$('.showme')` to get a jQuery object containing all the elments that have this class.

If you have to run some logic on each matching element, you would use `.each()`, like this:

```
$('#tryBTN').click( function() {
    $('.showme').each( function( i, element ) {
        if( $(element).css('visibility') == 'hidden' ) {
            $(element).css( 'visibility', 'visible' );
        }
    });
});
```

But you don't need to check whether an element has `visibility:hidden` before changing it to `visibility:visible`. You can just go ahead and set the new value. So you can simplify the code to:

```
$('#tryBTN').click( function() {
    $('.showme').each( function( i, element ) {
        $(element).css( 'visibility', 'visible' );
    });
});
```

And now that the only thing we're doing inside the loop is setting the new `visibility`, we don't even need `.each()`, since jQuery will do the loop for us when we call `.css()`. (Thanks @TemaniAfif for the reminder.)

So the code becomes very simple:

```
$('#tryBTN').click( function() {
    $('.showme').css( 'visibility', 'visible' );
});
```

Comment: and why the each ? you can simply apply CSS directly, no ?

Comment: D'oh! Thanks, @TemaniAfif. As one of the very first jQuery developers I should know better. :-) I'll tell you how I ended up [writing it the long way](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47895801/revisions) with `.each()` - my first pass was to use the class instead of sequential IDs, but I left in the code to check the `visibility` before setting it. If course in that case you would need `.each()`. Then I realized the test wasn't necessary and took it out, but didn't take a second look to notice that with this change, `.each()` wasn't needed any more either.

Comment: yes i was sure it was code updating and you didn't notice the simplification ;)